# Stored Procedures to insert into History table on Create/Update/Delete?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, stored-procedures, dbcontext

I'm developing an MVC5/EF Code-First Application. Does anyone know how to implement a stored procedure so that anytime a new record is `inserted` or a current record `updated` the record gets stored in my `INV_AssetsHistory` table?

My `INV_Assets` table is defined as:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using GridMvc.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using InventoryTracker.Models;

namespace InventoryTracker.Models
{
    [GridTable(PagingEnabled = true, PageSize = 30)]
    public class INV_Assets 
    {
        // Setting GridColumn Annotations allows you to use AutoGenerateColumns on view to auto create the Grid based on the model.


        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int Model_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Model_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Models Model { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Manufacturer_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Manufacturer_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Manufacturers Manufacturer { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Type_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Type_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Types Type { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Location_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Location_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Locations Location { get; set; }

        public int Vendor_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Vendor_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Vendors Vendor { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Status_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Status_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Statuses Status { get; set; }

        public string ip_address { get; set; }

        public string mac_address { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string note { get; set; }
        public string owner { get; set; }

        //[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        //[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:C}", ApplyFormatInEditMode=true)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#,###0.00}", ApplyFormatInEditMode=true)]
        public decimal cost { get; set; }
        public string po_number { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string description { get; set; }

        public int invoice_number{ get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string serial_number { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string asset_tag_number { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? acquired_date { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? disposed_date { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? verified_date { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime created_date { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string created_by { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
        public DateTime? modified_date { get; set; }

        public string modified_by { get; set; }

        // Flag to specify if item is available? (Not signed out, not auctioned, recycled, etc.)
        //public bool available { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And my `INV_AssetsHistory` table I've set up as thus (I viewed this as a stand alone table with no key values linking it to other tables; the only major difference between this and `INV_Assets` is the `Id` field for the current table and the `AssetsId` to designate the asset):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using GridMvc.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using InventoryTracker.Models;

namespace InventoryTracker.Models
{
    public class INV_AssetsHistory
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int AssetId { get; set; }

        //public int Model_Id { get; set; }
        //[ForeignKey("Model_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Models Model { get; set; }

        [Required]
        //public int Manufacturer_Id { get; set; }
        //[ForeignKey("Manufacturer_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Manufacturers Manufacturer { get; set; }

        [Required]
        //public int Type_Id { get; set; }
        //[ForeignKey("Type_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Types Type { get; set; }

        [Required]
        //public int Location_Id { get; set; }
        //[ForeignKey("Location_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Locations Location { get; set; }

        //public int Vendor_Id { get; set; }
        //[ForeignKey("Vendor_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Vendors Vendor { get; set; }

        [Required]
        //public int Status_Id { get; set; }
        //[ForeignKey("Status_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Statuses Status { get; set; }

        public string ip_address { get; set; }

        public string mac_address { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string note { get; set; }
        public string owner { get; set; }

        //[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        //[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:C}", ApplyFormatInEditMode=true)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#,###0.00}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public decimal cost { get; set; }
        public string po_number { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string description { get; set; }

        public int invoice_number { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string serial_number { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string asset_tag_number { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? acquired_date { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? disposed_date { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? verified_date { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime created_date { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string created_by { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
        public DateTime? modified_date { get; set; }

        public string modified_by { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I was reading over [THIS](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/stored-procedures-in-entity-framework-6-in-mvc-5/) article and attempting to implement my desired functionality. In my `InventoryTrackerContext.cs` file I have the following:

```
namespace InventoryTracker.DAL
{
    public class InventoryTrackerContext : DbContext
    {
        public InventoryTrackerContext()
            : base("InventoryTrackerContext")
        {

        }

        public DbSet<INV_Assets> INV_Assets { get; set; }
        public DbSet<INV_Models> INV_Models { get;set; }
        public DbSet<INV_Manufacturers> INV_Manufacturers { get;set; }
        public DbSet<INV_Types> INV_Types { get; set; }
        public DbSet<INV_Locations> INV_Locations { get; set; }
        public DbSet<INV_Vendors> INV_Vendors { get; set; }
        public DbSet<INV_Statuses> INV_Statuses { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
             modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
             modelBuilder.Entity<INV_Assets>().MapToStoredProcedures();
        }
```

While following the article, I added this (`modelBuilder.Entity<INV_Assets>().MapToStoredProcedures();`) particular line of code and updated my context. Now in my `Server Explorer` for `InventoryTrackerContext` connection, I have 3 stored procedures titled `INV_Assets_Delete/Insert/Update`. For example, the `Update` is defined as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[INV_Assets_Update]
    @Id [int],
    @Model_Id [int],
    @Manufacturer_Id [int],
    @Type_Id [int],
    @Location_Id [int],
    @Vendor_Id [int],
    @Status_Id [int],
    @ip_address [nvarchar](max),
    @mac_address [nvarchar](max),
    @note [nvarchar](max),
    @owner [nvarchar](max),
    @cost [decimal](18, 2),
    @po_number [nvarchar](max),
    @description [nvarchar](max),
    @invoice_number [int],
    @serial_number [nvarchar](max),
    @asset_tag_number [nvarchar](max),
    @acquired_date [datetime],
    @disposed_date [datetime],
    @verified_date [datetime],
    @created_date [datetime],
    @created_by [nvarchar](max),
    @modified_date [datetime],
    @modified_by [nvarchar](max)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE [dbo].[INV_Assets]
    SET [Model_Id] = @Model_Id, [Manufacturer_Id] = @Manufacturer_Id, [Type_Id] = @Type_Id, [Location_Id] = @Location_Id, [Vendor_Id] = @Vendor_Id, [Status_Id] = @Status_Id, [ip_address] = @ip_address, [mac_address] = @mac_address, [note] = @note, [owner] = @owner, [cost] = @cost, [po_number] = @po_number, [description] = @description, [invoice_number] = @invoice_number, [serial_number] = @serial_number, [asset_tag_number] = @asset_tag_number, [acquired_date] = @acquired_date, [disposed_date] = @disposed_date, [verified_date] = @verified_date, [created_date] = @created_date, [created_by] = @created_by, [modified_date] = @modified_date, [modified_by] = @modified_by
    WHERE ([Id] = @Id)
END
```

Based on the article, I assumed this procedure would fire automatically when I updated my `INV_Asset` record. If it is though, it's not adding a record to my `INV_AssetsHistory` table as I intended -- which looking at the SQL appears to not be what is instructed.

Do I need to manually modify my`INV_Assets_Update` stored procedure, or is there a few lines of simple code I'm overlooking/unaware of to get what I'm wanting accomplished? Anyone more experienced care to weigh in?

I'm currently using the local DBContext, but in `PROD` the tables will be in an ORACLE database.

Comment: A trigger on INV_ASSET would do the job quickly and simply.

Comment: I am not sure EF is the best option here, looks like a perfect scenario for the database trigger.

Comment: Can either of you provide an example or link to how to set that up? I'm somewhat familiar with Sequel Server/Management Studio, but ORACLE and Toad are new technologies/tools for me.

Answer (score 1):

as already commented by others, use a trigger, here is an example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER INV_ASSET_BRIU ON INV_Asset
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
FOR EACH ROW IS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO INV_AssetHistory(id, col1, col2, ..., action_timestamp)
    VALUES (:NEW.id, :NEW.col1, :NEW.col2, ..., SYSTIMESTAMP);
END;
```

with this trigger each version will be inserted to the table INV_AssetHistory

Comment: Thanks. I kind of know how to go about this in the actual DB (my experience is using SSMS), but do you know how I can implement/test this trigger out using the local DBContext `InventoryTrackerContext` I am currently using for my Application? I am working in VS2013 if that helps.

Comment: I don't know how to create triggers using SSMS, but there is sure a possibility to create triggers in T-SQL.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I've done Stored Procedures in Sequel Server Management Studio (SSMS), but haven't experimented much with Triggers -- never done either in VS2013.

Comment: select the trigger actions INSERT and UPDATE; then write: `INSERT INTO INV_AssetHistory SELECT * FROM inserted` as the insert/update statements (`inserted` contains the new values as `:NEW` in Oracle)